# Ports are set to allow in ufw but shows blocked

Tags: firewall, ufw

I am very new to using ubuntu, I was trying to configure my plesk email but realized I am not able to receive or send emails. I have configured the correct ports with ufw allow, but they show blocked on an online port scanner.

[The ports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Fzxz.png)

All these ports also are allowed in, however on the port scanner website this is what it shows for those ports,
[port 21](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6IR2.png)
[25](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJ1Xi.png)

All the other ports such as pop3 ssl, imap ssl also show closed. I have enabled and disabled ufw to try updating it but it does not seem to work.